# Remove portion of a dataset filter

Tags: ruby, sequel

Given a [Sequel Dataset](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) that has multiple filters applied, how can I create a new dataset that removes or overrides one of the existing filters?

```ruby
ds1 = DB[:x].filter(a:1, b:2)
#=> <Sequel::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM x WHERE ((a = 1) AND (b = 2))">

ds2 = ds1.filter(a:42) # I want to CHANGE a, not add another
#=> <Sequel::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM x WHERE ((a = 1) AND (b = 2) AND (a = 42))">
```

The `Sequel::Dataset#unfiltered` method removes all filters (e.g. it removes `b=2`). While that would be easy to re-add in the above simple case, it would result in code duplication in my real case.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your selection rule in a Hash and reuse the hash:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

selection = { a:  1, b: 2 }
ds1 = DB[:x].where( selection )

selection[:a] = 5  #change data
ds2a = ds1.unfiltered.filter(selection) # change selection
ds2b = DB[:x].where( selection ) #Alternative usage

puts ds1.sql  #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 1) AND (`b` = 2))
puts ds2a.sql #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 5) AND (`b` = 2))
puts ds2b.sql #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 5) AND (`b` = 2))
```

---

I found a possibility to modify a dataset with the new methods `filter_exchange` and `filter_exchange!`.

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite

module Sequel
  class Dataset
    def filter_exchange!( filter )
      filter.each{|key, value|
        opts[:where].args.each{|arg|
          if arg.args.first == key
            arg.args.pop
            arg.args << value
          end
        }
      }
      self
    end
    def filter_exchange( filter )
      sel = self.unfiltered
      filter.each{|key, value|
        opts[:where].args.each{|arg|
          if arg.args.first == key
            sel = sel.filter(key => value)
          else
            sel = sel.filter(arg)
          end
        }
      }
      sel
    end
  end
end

ds1 = DB[:x].filter(a:1, b:2)
puts ds1.sql                        #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 1) AND (`b` = 2))
puts ds1.filter_exchange( a: 7).sql #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 7) AND (`b` = 2)
puts ds1.sql                        #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 1) AND (`b` = 2)
puts ds1.filter_exchange!( a: 7).sql#SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 7) AND (`b` = 2)
puts ds1.sql                        #SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE ((`a` = 7) AND (`b` = 2)
```

`filter_exchange!` modifies your original dataset command! Even a `ds.dup.filter_exchange!` will change your original selection.

With `filter_exchange` you get a modified dataset. (Not very well tested up to now).

Answer (score 1):

I guess its not their primary use case and you'd probably want to benchmark, but you could use [bound variables](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/prepared_statements.rdoc#placeholders)

```
# initial args
ds1 = DB[:x].filter(a: :$a, b: :$b).bind(a: 1, b: 2)
ds1.call(:first)  # or :select, :update, et al.

# then later
ds2 = ds1.bind(a: 42)
ds2.call(:first)  # uses a = 42 and b = 2

# or pass the args directly into call()
ds2.call(:first, a: 42)
```

Note that bound variables are only recognized when used with `call` and `prepare`, so you can't just use, e.g. `ds2.first`